# How can I send email to verify email owners from web-services?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, email, spring-mvc

My users in android app will enter email address and password. To confirm they are the owner of email, I will send a 6 digit code to their email address and save it in my database. Within 3 minutes user has to enter the received 6 digit code to confirm they are the owner and validate with database. Questions
1) How can I send email from my web-services? Right now my back end is in Java and using Jersey, jackson. What technology or API I need to mingle with?
 I want this email sending feature to be 100% up without any downtime as it is critical. 
2) Is Amazon SES https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/send-an-email/ a good solution?
Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You can send a mail to any mail server from your Java API via SMTP. You can use Java Mail or any other wrapper library (eg. Apache Commons Email). You will need a mail server to actually send the mails to the desired destinations.

Comment: Thank you very much. I realized that SMTP server is the solution. But have been searching for connecting my web app to SMTP server. I am searching for some quick tutorials. If you know some, please share. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend using the apache commons email library to format and send your emails. You may test that your API is sending the emails using  [Fake SMTP](https://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/)

Answer (score 0):

You can send a mail to any mail server from your Java API via SMTP. You can use Java Mail or any other wrapper library (eg. Apache Commons Email). You will need a mail server to actually send the mails to the desired destinations. You may test that your API is sending the emails correctly using [Fake SMPT Server](https://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/).

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to send mail to user with code

when the user fills the registration form then get the email id and send mail using below code

```
 <?php
 $to = $_POST['to'];
 $from = $_POST['from'];
 $subject = $_POST['subject'];
 $message = "From: ".$name."\r\n";\
 $headers = "From:" . $from;
 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
 ?>
```